# Teste Unitário Delphi

Tags: delphi, testes-de-unidade, tdd

Estou implementando o DUnit na empresa e a minha dúvida é a seguinte: existe alguma forma de realizar o click do botão de uma "ShowMessage", de um formulário eu consigo, mas gostaria que quando aparecesse a janela do showmessage, eu pudesse programar o click desse botão automaticamente, não havendo intervenção do usuário.
Alguém sabe se é possível fazer ou se tem alguma idéia diferente.

Desde já agradeço a colaboração de todos.

leandro paixão

Comment: E se em vez do showmessage você criasse um form no modelo de showmessage?

Comment: Você está tentando usar DUnit para testar rotinas com interação do usuário e ele não foi feito pra isso. O conceito e arquitetura xUnit é testar código de negócio, rotinas com entradas (parâmetros, por exemplo) que produzem determinadas saídas (retorno da função, persistência de dado, alteração do estado de entidades...). Se você precisa simular interação do usuário porque quer justamente testar a interface gráfica, precisa achar outra ferramenta. Se o que você quer testar é o código de negócio acoplado a este formulário, você precisa primeiro desacoplar ocódigo e daí o DUnit **talvez** sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TFProv_Principal.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Interval := 3000; // Tempo que a msg ficará na tela -> 3 Segs
Timer1.Enabled := True;
MessageBox(Handle, PChar(´Testando MessageBox com tempo pré-definido.´), Pchar(´Titulo´), 8224);
end;

procedure TFProv_Principal.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0,0,0);
Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Comment: Como sugestão, além de postar o código, faça um breve comentário a respeito do funcionamento dele e deixe dicas de como se deve implementar. Seria interessante também indicar uma referencia de leitura sobre o tema do problema(caso você tenha alguma).